# npm install error node-sass postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

Tags: node.js, npm

Здраствуйте. Появляется следущая ошибка при инсталировании:
[image: пример ошибки]

```
node -v: v12.16.3
npm -v: 6.14.5
node-sass -v:
```

пробовал разные, от `3.*.* до 4.*.*`

"Гугление" ефективного решения не дало. Возможный вариант - несостыковка версии ноды и node-sass (без решения). Возможно кто то сталкивался и знает выход. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, помогло следущее - https://riptutorial.com/ru/node-js/example/4578/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-node-version-manager--nvm-
Установил "неконфликтую" версию ноды (в моем случае 11.*.*) и на ней все заработало. Так же нужно было подобрать соответствующую версию node-sass.